# Make Link shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Is there a document shortcut for **Make Link** or where I can bind it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the URL highlighted, you can press ⌘K to open the Add/Edit Link sheet, followed by ↩︎enter/return to OK the sheet.